# Select count of 0 from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in sql-server with 400 columns and 200000 rows.
I want the count of all the records that have 0 as their value.

I am not sure how to write the "Select count(*) from table where 'all 400 attributes' = 0"
Select count(*) from table where attribute' = 0 will give value for only 1 column.
Is there any other way I can select all 0 from table without manually doing for each attribute?
Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Why do you have 400 columns?

Comment: A table with 400 columns? You don't need query help. Also please decide whether you're using SQL Server or MySQL.

Comment: Why do you have mysql **and** sql-server tagged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is sql-server can use this to build up the query

```
SELECT c.column_name + ' = 0 and '
  FROM information_schema.columns c
 WHERE c.table_name = 'table'
```